# Isn't there a Chrome Driver for integrating Sikuli with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, sikuli

I am trying to integrate the Sikuli with Selenium. All the articles I could find has below one:

```
SikuliFirefoxDriver driver = new SikuliFirefoxDriver();
```

Source : https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver

My app is supposed to be using Chrome. Isn't there a parallel facility provided by Sikuli for Chrome browser that will allow me to use it with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

No; there is no Sikuli driver implementation for other browsers. Having said that, you can use sikuli-api directly in your code to automate steps (along with selenium api). Sample code can be found [here](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/030-java-dev.html)